# undefined reference to symbol even when nm indicates that this symbol is present in the shared library 2

Tags: linker, g++, undefined-reference, dynamic-library

I found same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456581/undefined-reference-to-symbol-even-when-nm-indicates-that-this-symbol-is-present) here but the answer doesn't help me.

I'm writing test app to use nglib library. But when I try to compile it I get undefined references:

```
$ g++ test1.cpp -L. -lnglib
test1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
/tmp/cchcKZfx.o:test1.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'Ng_Init()'
/tmp/cchcKZfx.o:test1.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'Ng_NewMesh()'
...
/tmp/cchcKZfx.o:test1.cpp:function main: error: undefined reference to 'Ng_Exit()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

but for example when I search for Ng_Init() in libnglib.so, I get positive result.

```
$ nm -D libnglib.so | grep Ng_Init
000000000008d0d0 T _ZN5nglib7Ng_InitEv
```

So I'm perplexed why I'm getting undefined reference errors ?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_ZN5nglib7Ng_InitEv` demangles to `nglib::Ng_Init()` which is not the same as `Ng_Init()`.